# How to launch a lua server?

Tags: shell, lua, actionscript-3

I wanted to know how to launch a lua server. I found a game I'd like to play with friends, though we do not know how to start the server that is `.lua`.

The game [is here](http://www.module801.com/bloup/bloup_ld33.zip). Could you help us please?

Comment: Yes, and the game is open source. But i don't know how to launch the .lua...

Answer (score 1):

Are you on Windows or Linux?

If Windows, get the LuaForWindows binaries from https://github.com/rjpcomputing/luaforwindows

If Linux, get the `lua` package from your distro's repository.

Then, open a command prompt and run the line:

```
lua /path/to/file/somefile.lua
```

using your own filepath of course. See if the server launches that way.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows: Download Lua from [here](http://luabinaries.sourceforge.net/).
For Linux check [this website](https://www.lua.org/download.html).
After you downloaded them either put the files in your current working directory or in the folder you want to execute them from.
Finally run this:
`lua ./path/of/server.lua`